# Primefaces p:dataTable showing without message "No records found."?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a p:dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable var="ind" value="#{logIndPersistBean.list}" paginator="true" rows="10"
                        id="table"  rowStyleClass="odd-row, even-row">

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            List of Logs
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column headerText="Name" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{ind.name}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Date" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{ind.date}" />
                        </p:column>

                        </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
```

When i start a new search, if none register returns, the dataTable show a message "No records found.", is there a way to a dataTable just show a empty message, only the empty list ?

If it's relevant i'm using primefaces 4.0

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer to the Primefaces User Guide for more information on the attributes (http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_0.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot Fritz !

Comment: No problem. And i suggest trying to update your Primefaces version to the latest 5.1 o 5.2. I quote "Migrating from PF4 to PF5 should be an easy task, many of the changes are backward compatible with deprecation notices" (http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3132)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add emptyMessage="" to your data table attributes.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that i would change the css